# JPA/ Hibernate Run time catch Unique constraints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is there any way in Jpa/ Hibernate to catch unique constraints to catch in run time code before going to the oracle db.

Scenario: doing JPA batch inserts ( we have one to many parent - child relationships with in the batch) and there are 2 sets of unique constraints for some child tables

Problem : when the constraint failed exception on one of the child tables is coming from oracle, we are not able to track which one in the batch failed that constraint, to solve this we want to catch before itself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store it in some set.(Before storing encode it it first)

Then again get it from set and decode it.

Then perform batch insertion.